# How do I make my header, function and main file work together, I always get: error: Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, function

I made a very simple C++ program where the goal is to use functions in different files. The function justs prints out a certain message passed in a parameter. After some research, I read that for such project, I need 3 files: the main, the header and the function (apparently I shouldn't put the function code in the header file.) I now have three files:

- main.cpp (main file)
- simple.h (header file (function definition))
- simple.cpp (function file)

Whenever I try to make them work together, I always get the same error:

```
    C:\Users\juuhu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQRa0R0.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `message(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the code of the three files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simple.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    message("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

simple.h

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED
#define SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

void message(std::string message);

#endif
```

simple.cpp

```
#include "simple.h"

void message(std::string message){
    cout << message;
}
```

Comment: Hi! If you have questions about why your question receives downvotes, you can ask it in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Are you sure all of these are in the project? It sounds like only `main.cpp` is being built. Maybe you have the option on for using the last successful build of `simple.cpp` since the file as it is shouldn't compile.

Comment: How do you compile and link them ("try to make them work together")?

Comment: Hey I know it's late, but recently I saw on a website that I had to compile each other separately: g++ main.cpp simple.cpp It worked but could you explain me why? I thought I only had to compile main.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was use visual studio 2019 to compile your code. First compile error output:"Error    C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   message".

When I add `#include<iostream>` in simple.h and change simple.cpp message function  the `cout` to `std::cout`, the program output "Hello world!"

- simple.h

```cpp
#ifndef SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED
#define SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

void message(std::string message);

#endif
```

- simple.cpp

```cpp
#include "simple.h"

void message(std::string message) {
    std::cout << message;
}
```

you can try again, hope you are successful to compile the code and get your to want.

Comment: Why put `#include <iostream>` in simple.h when it's only needed in simple.cpp?

Answer (score -1):

You haven't link the function defination file to the header file.

**simple.h**

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED
#define SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include "simple.cpp" // include the simple.cpp file

void message(std::string message);

#endif
```

Comment: Including a .cpp file defeats the purpose of having one in the first place.